# Equivalence of closed level sets and lower semi continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space, and $f:E\to [-\infty,\infty]$ be a function whose all level sets are closed. Theorem 2.6 in [this beautiful book](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611974997) claims that $f$ is lower semi-continuous. The proof is short but I am not sure how to prove the (probably trivial) part that says

> Take $\alpha$ that satisfies $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf f(x_n)<\alpha<f(x^*).$$ Then there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ such that $f(x_{n_k})\leq \alpha$ for every $k\geq 1$.

How can we formally prove that the "then" part is correct? Why can't we use "$<\alpha$" instead of "$\leq \alpha$"? Does it suffice to use only the first inequality without the second one?

Comment: The author talks about $\alpha$-level sets and uses $\liminf$ where you use $\lim$. It is probably worthwhile if you edit the question to fix that and give more details to enable an adequate answer.

Comment: Look up something along the lines, “lim(inf) iff. there is a subsequence with…”

Comment: Hint 1. When liminf is less than $\alpha$ then there is a subsequence that converges to that liminf. Hint 2. Yes we could use $<\alpha$ but the weaker (a little confusing) $\le \alpha$ will do. Hint 3. So far we needed only the first inequality.

Comment: Thanks! so this follows directly from the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem?

Comment: Bolzano-Weierstrass says -as we know- that a bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. For our stuff in OP however, we just need to exploit the definition of liminf as the smallest accumulation point. I appreciate your efforts to understand this in detail but I don't think for this it requires to reopen the question. When you read somebody's detailed answer you may just have similar questions on that. Better to struggle until it is fully understood. Feel free to ask more questions in the comments.

Comment: Apologies, but I am a bit confused. If I understood correctly, you mean that the question was closed since it is too trivial. This makes sense, since I am new to this area and obsessed with the details. However, the justification above for closing says "This question needs details or clarity". Can you suggest what details or clarity is missing? Or everything is just fine as is and I should just ignore and move on? Thanks again for your time and patience.

Comment: If you want that question re-opened I suggest that you take that (admitetly) beautiful book and add more steps of that proof to the question. Already confusing $\alpha$-level sets with "all level sets" shows some lack of precision which makes it not very enticing for us to fix all those problems and just repeat what we read in that book. Make some contributions and you will get better answers. We need to know in particular *what exactly* is unclear to you.

Comment: The question is already in review for the second time now. If editing the actual content doesn't have an impact, whining about "admins" or the fact that reviews are not instantaneous will definitely not help.

Comment: @Nij, I am not wining, just try to understand why the question was closed.

Comment: @Kurt, thanks again. I believe I got it and will submit a detailed and complete proof for Theorem 2.6 so that you will only have to approve, understand what I was missing, and in the hope to contribute something to the reader and not only waste your time. Currently, I have only one question: when I wrote "all level sets" I meant of course to the union of $\alpha$-level sets, over every $\alpha\in R$. Is this the imprecision you was referring to? Or are there actually other types of level sets?

Comment: The author defines those $\color{red}{\alpha}$-level sets very clearly. We don't need others. Please get into your rabbit hole now and do the work you promised.

Comment: I am on it. It is not a good excuse, but my wording "whose all level sets are closed" was based on the author's words "suppose that all the level sets of f are closed."

Comment: Done! My original misunderstanding was proving Hint 1 from @KurtG above, which is now Lemma 2 in my answer. As stated, a reference to a similar existing proof and any feedback will be appreciated. As a CS graduate that needs this claim for Machine Learning (ML) applications, there must be others that are interested but lack the real-analysis background or forgot the calculus that is less common in ML papers.

Answer (score 1):

The following very detailed answer is based on the hints from @Kurt in the comments with the original proof in the book. I was mainly missing Lemma 2 below, which seems to be trivial to the author, as the OP staff and commenters, and I will appreciate a reference to a book or the closest lemma. The other lemma and definitions can be found in the cited lectures which were taken from [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1493927116).
There are related questions in this web-site on the main claim, so I hope it would help them too and appreciate any feedback.

$\newcommand{\REAL}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\Lev}{\mathrm{Lev}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{\REAL}}$
$\newcommand{\br}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}$

**Notation and basic definitions.** The set $\N$ is the union of natural numbers (excluding zero). The set $E$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space (the references may assume $E=\R$ but the proofs hold for the general case).
A *sequence* in a set $S$ is a function $y:\N\to S$ which is denoted by $\br{y_n}_{n\in \N}:=\br{y(n)}_{n\in \N}$. For a strictly increasing sequence $\br{n_k}_{k\in \N}\subseteq \N$, the sequence $\br{x_{n_k}}_{k\in N}$ is called a *subsequence*. The *limit inferior* of a sequence $\br{x_n}_{n\in \N}$ is defined by

\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{infdef}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf x_n:
=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\inf_{m\geq n} x_m).
\end{equation}
A function $f:E\to [-\infty,\infty]$ is called *lower semicontinuous at $x\in E$* if
\begin{equation}\label{semis}
f(x)\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf f(x_n).
\end{equation}
for any sequence $\br{x_n}_{n\in \N}\subseteq E$ for which $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$. The function is *lower semicontinuous* if it is lower continuous at every $x\in E$. For every $\alpha\in\R$, the *$\alpha$-level set* of a function $f:E\to[-\infty,\infty]$ is the set
$$\Lev(f,\alpha):=\br{x\in E\mid f(x)\leq \alpha}.$$

**Lemma 1** (all subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit as the original sequence) [Theorem 2.5.2 [here](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://math.byu.edu/%7Ebakker/M341/Lectures/Lec10)]
Let $\br{x_n}_{n\in \N}\subseteq E$ and $x\in E$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}=x.
$$
Let $\br{x_{n_k}}_{k\in N}\subseteq \br{x_n}_{n\in N}$ be a subsequence.
Then
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{n_k}=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n.
$$
$\square$

**Lemma 2** [Could not find a reference and will appreciate one]
Let $\br{x_n}_{n\in \N}\subseteq \REAL$ be a sequence, and $\alpha\in\REAL$ such that
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{limm}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf x_n<\alpha.
\end{equation}
Then, there is a subsequence $\br{x_{n_k}}_{k\in N}$ such that $x_{n_k}<\alpha$ for every $k\in N$.
$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$

**Proof.**
Let $\ell:=\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf x_n$, $\eps:=\alpha-\ell$, $n_0=-\infty$, and $k=1$. By \eqref{limm} and Definition \eqref{infdef}, there is $z\in \N$ such that, for every $n>\max\{z,n_{k-1} \}$, $$|\inf_{m\geq n}x_{m}-\ell|<\eps.$$
In particular, $\inf_{m\geq n}x_{m}<\ell+\eps=\alpha$.

By the last inequality and the definition of $\inf$, there is an integer $n_k\geq n$ such that $x_{n_k}<\alpha$. By definition of $n$ and $n_k$, we also have $n_k\geq n >n_{k-1}$.
Recursively applying the above construction of $x_{n_k}$ for every $k\geq1$, yields the desired subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\N}$.

$\square$

We are now ready to prove the main claim.

**Theorem** (closedness of level-sets implies lower semicontinuity) [Theorem 2.6 [here](https://%5B3%5D%20https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611974997)]
Let $f:E\to[-\infty,\infty]$ such that, for every $\alpha\in\REAL$, the level-set
$$\Lev(f,\alpha):=\br{x\in E: f(x)\leq \alpha}$$
is closed. Then $f$ is lower semicontinuous.

**Proof.**
Suppose that all the level sets of $f$ are closed.
Assume by contradiction that $f$ is not lower semicontinuous. Hence, there is $x\in E$ and $\br{x_n}_{n\in \N}\subseteq E$ such that
\begin{equation}\tag{5}\label{liminfn}
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\tag{6}\label{liminf}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf f(x_n)< f(x).
\end{equation}
By \eqref{liminf}, and since $\REAL$ is continuous, there is $\alpha\in\REAL$ such that
\begin{equation}\tag{7}\label{asscon}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf f(x_n)<\alpha <f(x).
\end{equation}
Using the first inequality of \eqref{asscon}, substituting $x_n:=f(x_n)$ in Lemma 2, yields that there is a subsequence $\br{f(x_{n_k})}_{k\in \N}$ such that $f(x_{n_k})<\alpha$ for every $k\in \N$. That is,
\begin{equation}\tag{8}\label{knk2}
\text{$x_{n_k}\in \Lev(f,\alpha)$ for every $k\in \N$.}
\end{equation}
By Lemma 1 and \eqref{liminfn}, respectively,
\begin{equation}\tag{9}\label{knk1}
\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{n_k}
=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n
=x.
\end{equation}

Since $\Lev(f,\alpha)$ is closed by assumption, \eqref{knk2} and \eqref{knk1} implies $x\in \Lev(f,\alpha)$. That is, $f(x)\leq \alpha$, contradicting the last inequality of \eqref{asscon}.

$\square$

Comment: Haven't checked all details but looks like huge progress. BTW we don't ask for references of Lemmas that we can undoubtedly prove ourselves (your Lemma 2 for example).

Comment: @KurtG., I was just curious if there is a simpler proof for Lemma 2. In the Edit, I put the one-liner that I expected and thought about now. Hope it is also correct.

Comment: There is certainly a simpler proof of Lemma 2 and when you stick to the subject you will realise at some point that it will not need a written proof at all. Hint: formalize the fact that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n$ is the smallest limit point of the sequence. Your edit does not look correct. Alternatively you can also formalize the fact that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n$ is $\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n$ where $y_n$ is the non decreasing sequence $y_n:=\inf_{k\ge n}x_k\,.$

Comment: If in your edit you are trying to say that for every $k\ge 1$ there exists an $x_{n_k}\in[\ell,\ell+(\alpha-\ell)/k]$ (***period***) - then it is correct. There is some extra stuff that is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for reading @KurtG. . Are you sure? I added it because otherwise you can choose, say, $x_{n_1}:=x_4$ and $x_{n_2}=x_3$. In this case, ${x_{n_k}}$ is not a subsequence, since the constraint $n_1<n_2$ is not satisfied.

Comment: I am addressing this in an answer. How everyone writes it is ultimately a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Proof that $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n<\alpha$ implies the existence
of a subsequence $(x_{m_n})$ whose limit is less than $\alpha\,:$

- Since $\ell$ is the smallest limit point there exists (by definition of limit point) a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ whose limit is $\ell$. Done.
- When you use the alternative definition of $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$ as being the limit of the
  sequence $y_n=\inf\limits_{m\ge n}x_n$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ s.t. for all $n\ge N$ we have $y_n\in
  (\ell-\varepsilon,\ell+\varepsilon)\,.$ In particular this holds for
  $$
  \epsilon=\alpha-\ell\,.
  $$Since $y_n$ is an inf there exists an $m\ge n$ s.t. $x_m\in(\ell-\varepsilon,\ell+\varepsilon)\,.$ We take the smallest such $m$ and label it $m_n$ since it depends on $n\,.$
  Likewise, for $k>n$ there exists a smallest $m_k\ge k$ s.t. $x_{m_k}\in(\ell-\varepsilon,\ell+\varepsilon)\,.$ Clearly, $m_k\ge n\,.$ If $m_k$ were less than $m_n$ this would contradict the definition of $m_n\,.$ Therefore the sequence $(m_n)$ is increasing.

Comment: Awesome. Maybe my problem is that the "alternative definition" is the only definition I know, which is why I do not get the short version. Will try to figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: @DanFeldman Had to make a small correction that does not change the essence of it. What we are working on together here is to show that the first and the alternative definition are equivalent. This was one direction. Please try to prove the other one.